# fabricjs how i can make an angle measurement?

Tags: fabricjs

i want to use fabricjs for create an Object and can measure some images sections .

Update:

I follow sample of http://fabricjs.com/stickman/ and seems I have something but need to improve more

here is what i have https://jsfiddle.net/mavirroco/gtfw58st/

```
(function () {
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
    selection: false
});
var text1 = new fabric.Text('0 Deg', {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontFamily: 'Georgia',
    top: 10,
    left: 100
});
canvas.add(text1);

fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

function makeCircle(left, top, line1, line2, line3, line4) {
    var c = new fabric.Triangle({
        left: left,
        top: top,
        strokeWidth: 5,
        fill: '#fff',
        stroke: '#666',
        angle: -180,
        width: 10,
        height: 10
    });
    c.hasControls = c.hasBorders = false;

    c.line1 = line1;
    c.line2 = line2;
    c.line3 = line3;
    c.line4 = line4;

    return c;
}

function makeLine(coords) {
    return new fabric.Line(coords, {
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 5,
        selectable: false
    });
}

var line2 = makeLine([250, 175, 250, 250]),
    line3 = makeLine([250, 250, 300, 350]),
    line4 = makeLine([250, 250, 200, 350]);


canvas.add(line3, line4);

canvas.add(

makeCircle(line2.get('x2'), line2.get('y2'), line2, line3, line4),
makeCircle(line3.get('x2'), line3.get('y2'), line3),
makeCircle(line4.get('x2'), line4.get('y2'), line4));

canvas.on('object:moving', function (e) {
    var p = e.target;
    p.line1 && p.line1.set({
        'x2': p.left,
            'y2': p.top
    });
    p.line2 && p.line2.set({
        'x1': p.left,
            'y1': p.top
    });
    p.line3 && p.line3.set({
        'x1': p.left,
            'y1': p.top
    });
    p.line4 && p.line4.set({
        'x1': p.left,
            'y1': p.top
    });
    canvas.renderAll();

    dy = line3.get('y2') - line4.get('y2');
    dx = line3.get('x2') - line4.get('x2');
    theta = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    theta *= 180 / Math.PI // rads to degs
    text1.setText(parseFloat(theta).toFixed(2));
});
```

})();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
y11 = line3.get('y1');
y12 = line3.get('y2');
y21 = line4.get('y1');
y22 = line4.get('y2');

x11 = line3.get('x1');
x12 = line3.get('x2');
x21 = line4.get('x1');
x22 = line4.get('x2');

angle1 = Math.atan2(y11 - y12, x11 - x12);
angle2 = Math.atan2(y21 - y22, x21 - x22);  

angle = angle1 - angle2;  
angle = angle*180/Math.PI;
if(angle < 0) angle = -angle;
if(360 - angle < angle) angle = 360 - angle;
text1.setText(angle.toString());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gtfw58st/5/

Comment: nice is good i will improve a bit more for put the angle value inside the center triangle ..i belive this can be done with group ..not sure